# Clear out a textbox after submitting its content

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I struggled to figure out how to clear a textbox after submitting it's contents via a button control.

I would like to know if my solution is an accepted practice for initializing a control after an action has been made by a user.

**Is embedding event data (i.e. SendRequested) within a model an accepted practice for updating UI within Elm?**

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import WebSocket


main =
    program
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { input : String
    , messages : List String
    , sendRequested : Bool
    }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( Model "" [] False, Cmd.none )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = Input String
    | Send
    | NewMessage String


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg { input, messages, sendRequested } =
    case msg of
        Input newInput ->
            ( Model newInput messages False, Cmd.none )

        Send ->
            ( Model "" messages True, WebSocket.send "ws://echo.websocket.org" input )

        NewMessage message ->
            ( Model input (message :: messages) False, Cmd.none )



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    WebSocket.listen "ws://echo.websocket.org" NewMessage



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        inputElement =
            if not model.sendRequested then
                input [ onInput Input ] []
            else
                input [ onInput Input, value "" ] []
    in
        div []
            [ div [] (List.map viewMessage model.messages)
            , inputElement
            , button [ onClick Send ] [ text "Send" ]
            ]


viewMessage : String -> Html Msg
viewMessage message =
    div [] [ text message ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already keeping track of the `<input>`'s value in your model, it would be cleaner to use that as the `value` in your `view`, too.

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [] (List.map viewMessage model.messages)
        , input [ onInput Input, value model.value ] []
        , button [ onClick Send ] [ text "Send" ]
        ]
```

This way, your view is a pure representation of your model, and your model is kept in sync with user input.

I took the liberty of doing a quick pass over your code, additionally introducing record update syntax in your `update` function, as opposed to constructing a fresh record from scratch.

Adding or removing a field from a record needn't result in refactoring every single place you happen to modify the values of that record.

Comment: The "record update" is a great piece of feedback! Thanks for pointing that out.